# SQL Management Studio - Make my cursor more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make the following cursor run more efficiently:

```
USE AP
declare @vendorid int
declare @oloop int
declare @ocount int
declare @iloop int
declare @iloopt int
declare @invtot money
declare @invline money
DECLARE CursorOut CURSOR FOR SELECT VendorID FROM vendors
OPEN CursorOut;
set @ocount = (select count(*) from vendors)
WHILE @ocount>0
begin
 FETCH NEXT FROM CursorOut into @vendorid;
 set @iloopt= (select count(*) from invoices where
 vendorID=@vendorid)
 if @iloopt<>0
 begin
 set @iloop=@iloopt
 set @invtot=0
 DECLARE CursorIn CURSOR for select invoicetotal from
 invoices where vendorid=@vendorid
 open CursorIn;
 while @iloop<>0
 begin
 FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIn into @invline;
 set @invtot=@invtot+@invline
 set @iloop=@iloop-1
 end;
 close Cursorin
 DEALLOCATE Cursorin
 print 'VendorID= ' + convert(varchar,@vendorid,1) + ' Invoice Count ' +
convert(varchar, @iloopt,1) + ' Invoice Totals = ' + convert(varchar,@invtot,1)
 end;
set @ocount=@ocount-1
end;
close CursorOut
DEALLOCATE CursorOut
```

As you can tell, it's a lot of code. I've already fixed it up a bit, but it still takes quite a bit to run. Anyone notice anything else I can do to make it run faster?
EDIT: I figured it out!

```
use AP
select VendorID, count(*) as invcount, sum(invoicetotal) as invtotal
from invoices i
group by VendorID
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: The cursor continually prints out lines like this:
`VendorID = 34 Invoice Count 2 Invoice Totals = 1,200.12`
I'm thinking I could probably turn this into a simple SELECT statement.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking that too. ;-)